# Mixamo Rig Blender Bone Naming Convention

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

Mixamo names bones as mixamorig:LeftForeArm for example. For reasons, I need my bones to end in .L and .R to stick to Blenders naming convention so that I can more easily make other changes. Does Mixamo allow this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you can change this in Mixamo. But you can...

**Batch Rename Everything in Blender**:

Select the armature, switch to *Edit* mode. Select all bones, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or select the menu entry *Edit > Batch Rename...* of the main menu. In the popup panel:

- Restrict the search to `Selected` and the object type `Bones`
- Find: `^Left(.*)` and click the [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) button <kbd>*</kbd>
- Replace: `\1.L` and click the [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) button <kbd>*</kbd>

[image: batch rename]

**Note:** you need to use `\1` for the regex groups, not `$1` as described in the linked wikipedia article.

This renames every bone which name begins with `Left` and replaces it with *rest of the name*`.L`. All left bones are renamed. Repeat the steps for the other right side with adjusted values and it's done.

[image: renamed armature]

Comment: Hey I forgot I asked this. It works for me. Thanks!