# Copy pose from left side of armature to the right side or vice-versa, with an armature that isn't properly mirrored

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, game-engine

I'm working with an armature that came from one of the models from Half-Life 2, and I'm editing it to fit a different model. I'm trying to copy exactly what I do on one side of the armature to the other side, I just ( Ctrl + C ) the moved bone and then ( Shift + Ctrl + V ). But doing so doesn't effect the opposite bone, it just randomly rotates/moves the same bone, I'm guessing it's because the armature isn't mirrored properly.

I might fix it by renaming the opposite bones or deleting half the armature and mirroring it to the other side, but I can't edit the armature in such a way or else it won't properly work in the game engine I'm trying to port it to.

So is there a way to mirror the left/right side of an armature in pose or edit mode when the armature isn't properly mirrored in a way Blender can recognize?

Comment: Well, you’ve kind of answered your own question with an assumption. If the armature isn’t properly mirrored, of course Blender can’t recognize it, because that is kind of the definition of not being properly mirrored. But the thing is your armature may not be that. What are the names for two mirror image bones, for example?

Comment: Well the right upper arm bone is "ValveBiped.Bip01_R_UpperArm" and the left is "ValveBiped.Bip01_L_UpperArm". It seems each bone has either L or R in the name.

Comment: Literally my mental example of how the names could be causing the problem. This can be fixed with scripting, you pretty much just need to come up with a rule/code that can be applied to all the names and make them just UpperArm_L for example (it likes it at the end I think, or maybe that’s just me), and then iterate over bpy.data.armatures[“Chell.arma”].bones and adjust the names.

Comment: One additional note, though, bone roll could get ya. Do you need to preserve existing animations on the armature?

Comment: You could try to rename "ValveBiped.Bip01_R_UpperArm" to "ValveBiped.Bip01_R_UpperArm.R" with batch rename (Ctrl+F2), do the same for the left bones, then do the modifications, and rename the bones back to the original names. Here is an example for renaming: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/233401/107598