# Armature X Axis Mirroring Copy and Paste Only Affecting Same Bones

Tags: armature, mirror, pose-mode

I select all of the bones of my left side arm, and I copy pose with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[image: left arm bones selected]

and then select the corresponding right side bones and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, but get the following result of the left bones moving:

[image: right arm bones selected, but left arm bones moved]

I've also tried it with this box selected:

[image: pose options x-axis mirror checkbox]

my file:
[image]

edit:
Since the problem was due to Mixamo's naming convention's not matching up with Blender's (Blender's L/R suffixes vs Mixamo's Left Right prefixes) Here's a workaround [Mixamo Rig Blender Bone Naming Convention](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233401/mixamo-rig-blender-bone-naming-convention)

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonbots I added the .blend to the bottom of my post using your site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bones need to be correctly named, with the suffixe .R, .L, or _R, _L. Once done on a side, delete the opposite side and *Armature > Symmetrize*. Also apply the rotation of the object in *Object* mode.

Right now, as the name are not correct, you're just copying-pasting the pose from a bone to the same bone, and as the local orientation is bad, it flips the bone to the current opposite X side.

Comment: The bones were named by Mixamo after loading my mesh into their online rigger. AFAIK, they need those names in order to utilize all of the animations provided by Mixamo. Is adding L and R to the end of each bone name the only way for symmetry to work?  


I'm not sure what you mean that I'm "just copying-pasting the pose from a bone to the same bone." I copied from the left arm bones, then highlighted and pasted onto the right arm bones.  


Also, how is the local orientation bad? The X rotation on the armature is set to 90 by Mixamo as well. Not sure why.

Comment: Paste Pose Flipped will flip the pose. For a bone called bone.L for example (or bone_L or bone.left, etc, but not leftbone) it will flip the pose to the bone called bone.R. If Blender doesn't identify a bone that has the opposite suffixe the flipped pose will be assigned to the bone itself on the armature X axis, that's what happening right now.

Comment: Ok I see now, your response has opened up some better searches for a solve, but the Mixamo facet is another subject, so I think your answer satisfies my question. Thanks for your help with my first stack question ever haha